# What flag should I add to .clang-format file for space between type and protocol name?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, coding-style, clang

This is default behaviour:

```
  @property (nonatomic, assign) id<ViewDelegate> delegate;
  - (void)initWithRestaurant:(Restaurant<ViewDelegate> *)restaurant;
```

I want this:

```
  @property (nonatomic, assign) id <ViewDelegate> delegate;
  - (void)initWithRestaurant:(Restaurant <ViewDelegate> *)restaurant;
```

Can't find right flag here:
http://llvm.org/releases/3.4/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

Could this be `ObjCSpaceBeforeProtocolList` (documented [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html))?